# 404 error on drupal after migrating

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, wamp, wampserver

I have a Drupal website in the internet.

I want to work on local from now, so I install Wamp, I copy-pasted the apache filesystem of the website and made a sql dump with phpmyadmin.

I re-create the same database on phpmyadmin with the same name & datas than on the web.

Now, I can access to the main page (the ). All is ok, i see a node, I see the whole menu with links, ...

When I try to navigate or log, it give me 404 error, what is wrong? URL sounds great, when I try ti access to anode with the nodeid, 404 again.
I suspect WAMP but I don't know how fix that problem!

Thanks a lot to help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled - it isn't enabled by default on WAMP.

You can find instructions on how to do so [here](http://blog.cmstutorials.org/tutorials/tips-tricks/how-to-make-mod_rewrite-work-on-wamp).

Comment: In that case I would recommend finding your error log and relaying any relevant issues. (Click on WAMP icon -> Apache ->Apache error log)

Comment: @clement, mod_rewrite is called *rewrite module* in wampserver. It is not enabled by default. What happened is, Drupal had found it was enabled in your other server and allowed for url rewrite. Now it is trying to use it probably on your localhost which doesn't have url rewrite. A simple check would be appending '?q=' bewteen the path to drupal root ( local server path ) and the rest of the url. IF you can get over the 400 error, then you need to enable rewrite module.

Comment: @john : Yes thanks, it works now! I think there were an error in the htaccess or in the .gitcore hidden file don I re-download all files and now it's O-K-A-Y Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have uploaded the `.htaccess` file to Drupal's root directory.

Or try to access your website with `?q=`, like: `http://site.com/?q=admin`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have AllowOverride set to None in Apache. I believe that is the default, and it will prevent your .htaccess files from working (These are the files that make your URLs work).

Edit your Apache config file, search for every instance of AllowOverride and change it to "All", E.g:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Also make sure you actually copied the .htaccess file down, sometimes it's hidden.

Comment: Thanks I did it but it doesn't make any changes

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the local site in a sub folder? What's the local URL?

If the site is located in a subfolder, e.g. `http://localhost/drupal`, you'll need to add (or uncomment) a line in .htaccess that tells apache about the RewriteBase.

Answer (score -1):

AllowOverride was set to None in my httpd.conf.  Changing to AllowOverride All worked like a charm.

Remember to restart apache after the change.